# Android - Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS crashes on android 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app where users can click on certain buttons in my app and it will launch specific settings page from Android to the user. I uses the android API from their website http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);  
                    currentContext.startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DISPLAY_SETTINGS);   
                    currentContext.startActivity(intent);
```

These are some of the settings pages that my app will open. So far I have no problem launching these two intents from my app. However, when I try to launch the "About tablet" page with the code below, the Settings process crashes.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);   
                    currentContext.startActivity(intent);
```

It crashes on android 4.1.1 but it works fine on android 3.2. I'm still new to Android and I am at a lost on why it crashes. I'm new to StackOverflow as well. Hopefully I am able to get some answers here and nice to meet you all.

Here's my logcat:

```
09-19 09:50:12.830: I/ActivityManager(270): START {act=android.settings.DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity u=0} from pid 1627
09-19 09:50:12.910: D/dalvikvm(270): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 738K, 13% free 11824K/13575K, paused 62ms, total 62ms
09-19 09:50:13.010: W/System.err(1675): Removed 2131231183
09-19 09:50:13.020: W/System.err(1675): Removed 2131231190
09-19 09:50:13.060: D/LocalBluetoothProfileManager(1675): LocalBluetoothProfileManager construction complete
09-19 09:50:13.060: D/AndroidRuntime(1675): Shutting down VM
09-19 09:50:13.060: W/dalvikvm(1675): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d4c300)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at com.android.settings.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:167)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-19 09:50:13.060: E/AndroidRuntime(1675):     ... 11 more
09-19 09:50:13.090: W/ActivityManager(270):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity
09-19 09:50:13.090: W/ActivityManager(270):   Force finishing activity com.panasonic.tbexperience/.view.templates.TwoColumnsControlActivity
09-19 09:50:13.100: W/InputMethodManagerService(270): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41811de8 attribute=null
09-19 09:50:13.130: D/dalvikvm(1675): GC_CONCURRENT freed 187K, 4% free 6233K/6471K, paused 12ms+5ms, total 60ms
09-19 09:50:13.610: W/ActivityManager(270): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{417ea2e0 com.android.settings/.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity}
09-19 09:50:13.820: D/dalvikvm(445): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1020K, 33% free 14790K/22023K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
09-19 09:50:13.960: D/dalvikvm(445): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1057K, 30% free 15633K/22023K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
09-19 09:50:14.010: D/dalvikvm(445): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 362K, 24% free 16871K/22023K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
09-19 09:50:14.060: D/dalvikvm(445): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1289K, 20% free 17622K/22023K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 39ms
09-19 09:50:14.060: D/dalvikvm(445): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
09-19 09:50:14.060: D/dalvikvm(445): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 17ms
09-19 09:50:14.100: D/dalvikvm(445): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1693K, 25% free 16723K/22023K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
09-19 09:50:14.190: D/dalvikvm(445): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1126K, 21% free 17585K/22023K, paused 14ms+9ms, total 64ms
09-19 09:50:14.190: D/dalvikvm(445): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 50ms
09-19 09:50:14.390: I/dalvikvm(270): Jit: resizing JitTable from 8192 to 16384
09-19 09:50:16.870: I/Process(1675): Sending signal. PID: 1675 SIG: 9
09-19 09:50:16.890: I/ActivityManager(270): Process com.android.settings (pid 1675) has died.
09-19 09:50:16.890: W/ActivityManager(270): Force removing ActivityRecord{4166f668 com.android.settings/.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity}: app died, no saved state
09-19 09:50:16.890: W/InputMethodManagerService(270): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@415f2878 attribute=null
09-19 09:50:32.250: D/dalvikvm(1552): GC_CONCURRENT freed 424K, 9% free 6942K/7559K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 39ms
```

Also, I tried to directly set the classname for this api...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();   
                    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity");
                    currentContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Same thing happens.It works for android 3.2 but doesn't work in 4.1.1. I've got a feeling that maybe I did not get the right class name for the 4.1.1 version. Does anyone know the direct class name to open the "About Tablet" page or whether is it possible to open that page programmatically?

Regards, 
shuwen

Comment: As Commonsware comments on this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20018356/281545 this is not a problem with the `new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);` - but some other problem related to a change apparently between the APIs - somewhere you are passing a null and 4.1 does not tolerate it. Try in a test project where you open the  ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS in onCreate of main activity - does this work ?

Answer (score 0):

android api doc say:

```
In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.
```

so you should check this intent or catch this exception yourself.

Comment: Hi Mike,does that mean it is not possible to open that page at all? I've tried to directly set the class name without using the API as shown in my edited first post but it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Hi all, I'm still wondering if there's any way to work about this? Is it not possible after all to open the "About tablet" page through code for certain android models?

Comment: @user1679887: your problem is not related to the activity not existing - and certainly hardcoding the string is not a good idea. Look at the logcat - a nPE id thrown by the settings activity - not by the OP's code