# ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS Force close issue in nexus 10

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, settings

i am developing an android application where in i am opening the About Device intent programatically. I am using the below code for it.

```
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
```

Above code works fine in all devices but I am getting a force close in Nexus 10(tab).

Not getting where I am going wrong! Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Also post your logcat

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474777/android-settings-action-device-info-settings-crashes-on-android-4-1-1

Answer (score 0):

```
In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.
```

Check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Use Try & Catch block to ensure.