# Safeguard against "a matching Activity may not exist" in android settings

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-settings

The majority of the Activity Actions (used to launch various Settings activities) in the [Settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) class come with a warning :

> In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.

So how do I safeguard against this ?

```
try {
    final Intent i = new Intent(Settings. ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS); // say
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // not sure if needed
    startActivity(i);
} catch (Exception e) { // what should I catch here 
    // I would hate to catch Throwable, but should I ?
}
```

If I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474777/android-settings-action-device-info-settings-crashes-on-android-4-1-1) correctly for instance a runtime exception (NPE) is thrown. I would love to use something more specific though like [`ActivityNotFoundException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html) - but is it enough ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I read this correctly for instance a runtime exception (NPE) is thrown

No, that's some other problem. The `Intent` clearly worked, as the crash is coming from Settings itself, not the app that called `startActivity()`.

> I would love to use something more specific though like ActivityNotFoundException - but is it enough ?

It should be.

If you are concerned about that, or would rather be proactive, rather than just calling `startActivity()`, first use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()`. If that returns `null`, there is no activity that matches the `Intent`, and you should try something else.

Comment: `resolveActivity()` sounds like too much code for something that should not fail anyway - I went for the try catch. Thanks :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Note that even if the particular Settings `Intent` action is supported by a device, the particular *user* may not have access to it, if they are running on a restricted profile on Android 4.3+ tablets.

Comment: Any reason why startActivity not working after applying lock task mode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72571606/cannot-startactivity-using-intent